# How to tackle this problem related to column rank?

Tags: linear-algebra

**The question is** :

> If $A$ be a $m \times n$ matrix such that $A$ has full column rank.Then show that, $A$ is left invertible.

How can I proceed?Please help me.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: This asker, unfortunately, is clueless and is merely hoping some user is looking for a chance to earn rep, by answering.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

If $A$ has full column rank, what would be the outcome of performing Gaussian elimination on $A$? Each operation of Gaussian elimination can be thought of as an invertible elementary matrix...

Comment: what I have proved that if $A$ is of full column rank then $A^t A$ is invertible.So,it is row-equivalent to $I_n$.So there exists $n \times n$ invertible matrix $P$ such that $P(A^t A) = I_n$ i.e. $(PA^t)A = I_n$.Clearly we have a $n \times m$ matrix $E = PA^t$ such that $EA = I_n$ i.e. $A$ is left invertible.Which proves our claim.

Comment: @Rnbmath this is good

Comment: @amWhy i don't understand -- I gave the OP a hint which is standard practice here, and the OP converted it to a full fledged proof, adding an argument of his own. What is it that you did not like?

Comment: I now see the OP's comment above.  It would be best to encourage the OP to edit the question itself...Noting it is an edit based on a hint...Or even for you to edit into that post the comment, in quotes, from the op...The question could have been or could still be reopened with such an edit, because the OPs comment definitely showed effort and responsiveness.   I missed the OP's comment. I am sorry for my comment (though I did not downvote); you certainly didn't just hand over an answer, but engaged the OP to apply a hint, and in the end, to be successful and perhaps a bit more confident.

Comment: @amWhy no problem :), i just want to make sure i did not miss anything -- you are much more aware of what goes on on the site in general than i am...